# Viewing Photoshop images with layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-viewer, layers, psd

One of my friends likes to use layers in Photoshop to create interactive images. By interactive I mean turning on and off layers to get at different content.

For example he has a map of a twenty story building.

Anyway, I'd like to be able to view them, but can't. Irfanview has no problem with the Photoshop PSD, but doesn't support turning on/off the various layers.

Does anyone know of any program that does?

Comment: Do you need need to view several layers at once? If not the easiest way is to export the PSD as multi page PDF or TIFF. There are scripts for that in Photoshop under `file -> scripts - export`

Comment: Yes I do. In the map example, there are like 30 layers, some of which show things like gas pipes. I need to be able to veiw multiple layers at once and them on and off.

Comment: [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) will work. It has full support for PSD layers but is not exactly a lightweight viewer.

Comment: indeed it is not lightweight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pixlr Editor](http://pixlr.com/editor/) opens psd files, and you can see layers also. It's an **online** service.  There is tick box on the right-hand side: check, uncheck, and rock 'n' roll baby! :D